# How do I autostart an application in Gnome when a volume is mounted?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, autoplay

According to [Gnome's Desktop Application Autostart Specification](http://library.gnome.org/devel/autostart-spec/#mounting), I should be able to have a program execute simply by naming it any of ".autorun", "autorun", or "autorun.sh". None of these seem to work: I get a prompt from nautilus-autorun-software asking if I want to let it run, I say "Run", and it results in a dialog that says "Error autorunning software: Cannot find the autorun program". Is it a bug or am I not doing something correctly?

The autorun file contains the following:

```
#! /bin/sh
gnome-terminal -x sh -c '~/bin/podcatcher/copypodcasts.sh; echo Done!; read pause'
```

It works if I manually run the autorun file.

The filesystem is fat, here's the mtab entry:

```
/dev/sdd1 /media/disk vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush 0 0
```

Comment: What type of filesystem is on the volume, and what mount options are used? What are the effective permissions on the `autorun` file?

Comment: I think there should not be a space between `#!` and `/`,
eg. `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: @Martin It doesn't matter. http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#details

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense.

An USB drive is automatically mounted and owned by desktop user. But she must umount it and mount it again as root?  I can not see a practical use for this behaviour.

Anyway, I tested this root-mount and nothing showed up on the user desktop.

If you take a look on [nautilus code](http://nautilus.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.0.2-4/nautilus-autorun-software_8c_source.html), the `_check_file` function has no default for "must_be_executable", and calls to this function do not set that parameter.

The only way I got it working was this:

- format the USB drive in ext2 or ext3
- put an autoexec file on it
- change permissions to make this file executable by a desktop user (file can be owned by anybody)
- plug the USB drive and let gnome to automount it

Answer (score 1):

The cd is probably mounted with the `noexec` option.

Login as root on a terminal `umount` it and `mount` it again as root. This time as a user in the gui autorunning the cd should work. (It does for me with VirtualBox)

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot find the autorun program" may mean the file is not executable. If it's a CDROM, the `autorun` file has to have execute permissions. That requires Rock Ridge extensions to the ISO9660 file system at ISO image creation time.

I'm using the following procedure (**NOTE:** you'll need lots of disk space).

1. create a directory containing the files destined for the CDROM including autorun
2. make sure the files have execute permission. In the directory issue:

   ```
   chmod 555 *
   ```
3. create the ISO image using `mkisofs` or `genisoimage` (these appear to be the same program).

   ```
   genisoimage  -l -R -J -V disclabel -o directory.iso directory
   ```
4. Burn the iso to a blank CDROM using Brasero
5. This will yield a labeled CDROM with long file names, Joliet and RockRidge extensions.